# getting pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Expected 9 columns, got 1

Tags: csv, pyarrow

so I am trying apache arrow for the first time and want to read an entire directory of txt files into a pyarrow datastructure. I am getting

```
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: CSV parse error: Expected 9 columns, got 1
```

when I run the code below? no clue how to debug this. any help appreciated. ALSO if there's a book that covers python and pyarrow happy to read it.

```
import pyarrow.csv as csv

import pyarrow as pa  


l_all_files = ['x08.txt', 'x21.txt', 'x108.txt']

read_options = csv.ReadOptions( column_names= ('Sol' , 'H20', 'H50', 'H100',  'Date', 'Cv', 'Dys', 'Ple' , 'Cl') ,  skip_rows=26)


df_arrow_all = pa.concat_tables(( csv.read_csv(current_filename,read_options=read_options, ) for current_filename in l_all_files))
```

when the skip_rows = 26 is done this is what the line looks like

```
$sss        3431    3232    3249  25523  35.66    57  56le   77.73
```

Comment: Are the csv files properly formatted?  Are there commas in the first row? Is the entire header row quoted?

Comment: hi @Mike67  updated the question to show an example row. I thought csv.read_csv was smart enough to handle space separation instead of comma's. Also I thought by providing the column names there would be no need for headings inside the files.

Comment: There are no commas in the data. It's probably read as single column. Try `df_arrow_all = pa.concat_tables(( csv.read_csv(current_filename,read_options=read_options,parse_options=csv.ParseOptions(delimiter='\t' ) for current_filename in l_all_files)) `

Comment: I agree it's reading it as a single column. running  pandas against it works fine using  delim_whitespace=True,  Can't seem to figure out how to do same in pyarrow.

Comment: AND tried delimiter='\t' no luck.  This is a white space problem. I need to find out how to remove all spurious white space from the data. I would have thought Pyarrow CSV would have something like that but I can't find anything in the docs?

Comment: I don't see a whitepsace option for pyarrow: https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.csv.ParseOptions.html. You may need to load and resave the data using the csv module so the file has commas.

Comment: Hi @Mike67 thanks so much for trying to help. I can't see that the whitespace option either. I think I'll just continue to use pd.read_table instead as it works on this dataset right out of the box. I wanted to try Arrow ready for my move to julia but this is TOO hard :-) thanks again.

Comment: I opened https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/ARROW-10432 for supporting a general whitespace delimiter

Answer (score 0):

```
delmt = '\t' 
df = csv.read_csv(current_filename
                 ,read_options=read_options
                 ,parse_options=csv.ParseOptions(delimiter=delmt)
```

This worked for me!
credit: @Mike67